# What is weighting matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

What is weighting matrix? I heard from my teacher that it is used to calculate energy of some systems. But I don't have enough knowledge about it and can't imagine it. And I haven't found it in any book yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A weighting matrix $W$ is a matrix such that 
$$W^TW=I$$
where $W^T$ represents the transpose of matrix $W$ and $I$ the identity matrix.